# Flex paper integration in dspace

Tags: dspace

I have purchased ZINE license from flex paper. I am confused while integration in self hosted server, need help. If any one integrated please help on this.

Comment: Have you seen this documentation: https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/DSPACE/FlexPaper+Document+Viewer+for+XMLUI ?

Comment: Your question is not yet clear enough to answer.  What have you tried so far?  What is not working?  It might also be useful to start a conversation in one of the DSpace support channels: https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/DSPACE/Support

Comment: Yeah i have gone through those steps. I did not get the result. Can i have your email id, i will contact over there.

Comment: If you have a DSpace question, please send it to one of the community support channels such as Slack or e-mail.  Questions are answered in the forums so others can see the answers and conversation.

Comment: sure. thanks@terrywb